# Unable to set text box format to Rich Text for a calculated text field in a report

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a report based on the following query (qryrptTaskbyrepository):

```
SELECT qryRepository.RepName, 
[Source] & (" (Format: "+[tblsourceformat.Format]+")") & (" (Call: "+[Call]+")") AS SourceInfo, 
qryTask.ResearchTitle
FROM ((((qryTask LEFT JOIN qrySource ON qryTask.SourceID = qrySource.SourceID)
LEFT JOIN qryRepositoryAccess ON qrySource.SourceID = qryRepositoryAccess.SourceID)
LEFT JOIN qryRepository ON qryRepositoryAccess.RepositoryID = qryRepository.RepositoryID)
LEFT JOIN tblSourceFormat ON qryRepositoryAccess.Format = tblSourceFormat.FormatID
ORDER BY qryRepository.RepName, [Source] & (" (Format: "+[tblsourceformat.Format]+")") & (" (Call: "+[Call]+")"), qryTask.ResearchTitle;
```

[Source] and [tblsourceformat.Format] are plain text fields and [Call] is a Rich Text memo field. I want SoureceInfo `([Source] & (" (Format: "+[tblsourceformat.Format]+")") & (" (Call: "+[Call]+")"))` to display as multiline rich text (at least for the Call element, but can't set the field in the report to this option (presumably because it's based on a calculation in the query).

The record source for the report is:

```
SELECT * FROM qryrptTaskbyrepository WHERE ([RepositoryID] IS Null) OR [RepositoryID] IN (11,9);
```

The constraints on RepositoryID are determined by the user (by selecting items from a list of repositories) bewfore the report is generated.

What are my options for working round this? One possibility is obviously to display the Call info in a separate field; are there any others?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the issue is. I just tried something similar (I *think*) and it seemed to work okay. Please have a look at the sample database [here](http://wikisend.com/download/114906/richTest.zip).

Comment: @GordThompson True, the problem doesn't manifest in your sample whereas it does in my database. So I need to work out what the differences are. One obvious difference is that your text box in the report is defined at rich text whereas I'm prevented from setting mine to rich text.

Comment: When you try to set the `Text Format` property to `Rich Text` do you get an error saying "The setting you entered isn't valid for this property."?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes that's the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue:

Unable to change the `Text Format` property of a text box to `Rich Text`:

> The setting you entered isn't valid for this property.

I was able to recreate this issue when the `Record Source` property of the report was a SQL command ("SELECT ..."). The following workaround seems to have fixed it:

- With the report open in Design View, click the ellipsis button (`[...]`) beside the `Record Source` property of the form.
- Click the "Save As" button on the ribbon of the query designer. Save the query as "ReportQuery".
- Click the "Close" button (or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) to close the query designer. Choose "Yes" when prompted to save the changes.
- Check the `Record Source` of the report. It should now simply be `ReportQuery`.
- You should now be able to change the `Text Format` property of the [SourceInfo] text box to `Rich Text`.

Comment: Nice, but ss per the updated Q, my record source is dynamically generated based on constraints specified by the user,so i can't use a static query.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl Could you perhaps just update the `.SQL` property of the saved query (`QueryDefs("ReportQuery")`)?